# $_POST empty, sending form values with Ajax

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, ajax

**HTML**

```
<form action='insert.php' method='POST'>
    <p><b>Client:</b><input type='text' name='idclient'/> 
    <p><b>Total:</b><br /><input type='text' name='total'/> 

    <p><input type='submit' value='Save' id="btnSave"/>
    <input type='hidden' value='1' name='submitted' /> 
</form>
```

**PHP** (insert.php)

```
<?php
    echo file_get_contents('php://input');
    include_once "connect.php"; 

    if ($db_found){
        if (isset($_POST['submitted'])) {
            foreach($_POST AS $key => $value) {
                 $_POST[$key] = mysql_real_escape_string($value);                
            } 

            $sql = "INSERT INTO `mytable` ( `idclient` ,  `total` ,  ) " . 
                       "VALUES(  {$_POST['idclient']} , {$_POST['total']}  ) ";
            mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error()); 
        }       
    }
    mysql_close($db_handle);
?>
```

This works OK, but when I try to call the insert using Ajax the $_POST function is empty and I cannot access the values from the form.

This is the ajax code and the function call:

```
<form action="javascript:Save()" method='POST'>
```

**Ajax**

```
function Save()
{                           
  xmlHttp = getXMLHttp(); // returns a new XMLHttpRequest or ActiveXObject
  xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = function(){

    if(xmlHttp.readyState == 4) { 
      document.getElementById("btnSave").value = "Saved";
      document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = xmlHttp.responseText;
    }
    else{
      document.getElementById("btnSave").value = "Saving...";
    }
  }

  xmlHttp.open("POST", "insert.php", true);     
  xmlHttp.send(null);  // Do I need to create and pass a parameter string here?             
}
```

Doing an `echo file_get_contents('php://input');` indeed the $_POST is empty and the parameters values are not passed along.

I could concatenate the params value in the URL like this

```
xmlHttp.open("POST", "insert.php?idclient=123&total=43", true);
```

But, is there a way to use $_POST and take advantage of it?

Comment: You are not passing any parameters. And don't change the form `action` to `javascript:...`. The form will not work if JS is disabled. Listen to the `submit` event instead. So yes, you have to send the values. See the `send` documentation: [https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XMLHttpRequest#send()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XMLHttpRequest#send())

Comment: Rather than coding your own, I'd suggest using Jquery.  This becomes a one liner then.

Comment: Agree with @Daren Schwenke, no need to reinvent the wheel!

Comment: @Felix Kling Good idea with the submit event. However, when clicking the submit button all the input fields get cleared, looks like it's doing a page reload, why is that?

Comment: @CarlosTorres: Seems you are also sending a "normal" POST request (thus the page reloads). You have to prevent the default action of the `submit` event, which is submitting the form (obviously). You can do that by returning `false` from the event handler. To learn more about event handling I suggest to read the great articles at quirksmode.org: http://www.quirksmode.org/js/introevents.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the answers this is what I came up with:

```
var xmlHttp = getXMLHttp(); // returns a new XMLHttpRequest or ActiveXObject

function Save() {
  if(xmlhttp) { 
    xmlhttp.open("POST","insert.php",true); 
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange  = handleServerResponse;

    xmlhttp.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');    
    xmlhttp.send("idclient=" + document.getElementById("idclient").value  
                + "&total=" + document.getElementById("total").value); 
  }
}

function handleServerResponse() {
   if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4) {
     if(xmlhttp.status == 200) {
        alert("responseText= " + xmlhttp.responseText);
        document.getElementById("btnSave").value = "Saved";
        document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText; 
     }
     else {
        alert("Error during AJAX call. Please try again");
     }
   }
   else{
    document.getElementById("btnSave").value = "Saving...";
   }
}
```

After a while of searching I found out that defining as separate this function (and not inline in onreadystatechange, as in the original question) would get it to work.

```
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange  = handleServerResponse;
```

However, @Daren made a good point on "special" input values. For example, passing an '&' character in a string field will get incomplete values.

Comment: Strange, how you are still supporting IE5.5 and IE6 for this, since IE7+ versions have native `XMLHttpRequest` object `=P` ..  Bad copy-paste? Also, I should not that you can avoid sending the content-type header **IF** you are not using `$_POST` superglobal to read the values, but instead handle to input manually.

Answer (score 3):

You will need to set the content-type to `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` for the values to show up in `$_POST`.

For example `xmlHttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");` (if using an `XMLHttpRequest` object).

Comment: He also has to *send* the values.

Comment: I noticed that after posting the answer :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this for your form:

```
<form action="javascript:Save();return false;" method='POST'>
    <p><b>Client:</b><input id='client' type='text' name='idclient'/> 
    <p><b>Total:</b><br /><input id='total' type='text' name='total'/> 

    <p><input type='submit' value='Save' id="btnSave"/>
    <input type='hidden' value='1' name='submitted' /> 
</form>
```

And then make your call like so:

```
    xmlHttp.open("POST", "insert.php", true);
    var postStr = "idclient=" + document.getElementById("client").value + "&total=" + document.getElementById("total").value;
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
      xmlHttp.send(postStr);
```

Comment: This will cease to work, and not in a consistent way, if you have other than a-z0-9 in your input fields.  I'd again suggest Jquery where you have the .serialize() function which handles the urlencoding mess for you.

Comment: Thanks, I took your answer as a good starting point. I only needed to assign a function to the onreadystatechange event, otherwise it would hang and not finish.